# Jquery grab attr from automatically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children, attr

[image: http://i.imgur.com/p9ZkeIk.png]

I create a search engine and I have a problem.

```
<div class="singleresult" onclick="benger()">
<img class="profilepic" src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+this.id+'/picture"  alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="50">
<p class="name">'+this.name+'</p> 
<p class="tapto" algin="right">TAP TO UNLOCK</p> 
</div>
```

how to get the name value by clicking on the div? 
They have all the same classes

Comment: I tried to add onclick but then it did not work $(this) selector

Comment: share your implementation code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5sz4Lt6/

Comment: fiddle is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use $(this) Selector.

```
<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
<div class="test">test4</div>
<div class="test">test5</div>

$('.test').click(function() {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rfeuhyq0/

Comment: its working but i need get value from class name which is in div class singleresult

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. So we cant understand the real problem.                       <div class="singleresult" onclick="benger()"> <img class="profilepic" src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+this.id+'/picture"  alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="50">  <p class="name">'+this.name+'</p> <p class="tapto" algin="right">TAP TO UNLOCK</p> </div>                          from this which value you need

Answer (score 0):

This would retrieve specific text regarding which `.singleresult` DIV is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click",".singleresult", function(){
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    alert(name);
});
```

That's said, sounds like you want to retrieve specific data, element text shouldn't be used for that but instead any custom `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".singleresult", function(){
alert($(".name").text());
});
```